# Firestore notify changes

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My users have a subcollection called "friends" with two documents. One is "confirmed", for accepted friend requests, and "requests" for pending ones. Both contain an array of uids. What I am trying to do is check when a user receives a friend request using the collection onSnapshot method. I would need to see the changes from the old document to the new one. I wouldn't be able to use `collection_snapshot.docChanges()` since that only shows when a document is added, removed, or modified in a collection, not when a value in a document is added, removed, or modified.

So how would I listen for these changes in firestore?

Preferably I wouldn't have to compare the complete old document with the complete new modified document, since each document can have up to 200 uids, and be up to 1MB of data being transferred every update. I don't really see a way around it though, but wanted to check on stackoverflow first.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore realtime listeners work on document level and notify you when a document, was added, removed, or modified.

---

If a value is added, removed or modified in an existing document, that document is consider modified and a [Firestore listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) will fire a `modified` event. Give it a try, and you'll see that your listeners triggers for those changes too.

If you can't get it to work, please post a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried.

---

There is no way to receive notifications on specific modifications in a document. You will have to compare the previous and current snapshot yourself, or use another mechanism to find out exactly what changed inside the document.

If you don't want to do that, consider storing the fields on which you want that in separate subcollections, and listen on those instead of the parent document. That'll give you notifications of adds, deletes and changes at a lower level, but at the cost of having to read those additional documents.

Comment: Do you think I could do something like this with a cloud function?

Comment: The API in Cloud Functions on this front is no different than the one in client-side SDKs, so that won't make a difference.